# How does Wiki article go from one line to the next (linear regression)

Tags: regression, bayesian, model

I am stuck on how to get from one line to the next, as I'd like to understand how. (Our course requires a detailed proof involving this.)

[image]

Could anybody give me guidance how to show that LHS = RHS?

Comment: You've been *un*stuck?

Comment: Edited to "stuck". More crucially, please give the source of the Wiki[pedia?] article to give this context and wider value.

Comment: Yes, I have become unstuck......... Also, here's the link to the article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_linear_regression

Answer (score 2):

Because this is course work, I'll give you a few hints but leave it for you to complete.

Expanding the product gives

$$
y^Ty-y^TX\beta-\beta^TX^Ty+\beta^TX^TX\beta.
$$

You can insert the identity operation $(X^TX)(X^TX)^{-1}$ to get

$$
y^Ty-y^TX(X^TX)^{-1}(X^TX)\beta-\beta^T(X^TX)(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty+\beta^TX^TX\beta.
$$

Can you complete the square? Hint: $\hat\beta=(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$.